# NSURLSession and Connection terrible memory leaks

Tags: memory-leaks, ios8, xcode6, nsurlconnection, nsurlsession

every time i make a request to my web server via NSURLSession/Connection it leaks! To be honest it is not much but if you have to make a couple hundreds or thousands of calls this gets nasty.

I have been  on this for about a week now. I have tried everything. NO cache , little cache, setting everything on nil after the call is done(which is unnecessary), using datatask for sessions or just connection with requests. Every time i get a little more memory allocated and i have not found a way to solve this problem.

So i set up a little testApp:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property NSString *param;
@property NSURL * url;
@property NSURLConnection *test;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];



    self.param = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"hi"];
    self.url = [[NSURL         alloc]initWithString:@"http://127.0.0.1/xmlfile.php"];
    for (int i = 0; i<20000; i++){
        [self connect:self.param url:self.url];
    }
    NSLog(@"I AM DONE!");
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any   resources that can be recreated.
}


- (NSData *)connect:(NSString*)param url:(NSURL*)url{
    self.test = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:nil  delegate:self];
    [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
       return nil;
}

@end
```

i would love to add images of the memory usage but i am too new.
so just go here:
5k:iterations
http://i59.tinypic.com/123tts2.png
20k:
http://i59.tinypic.com/1zzqsrk.png

I have heard that this could be a problem with ios8.

Please help!

I am open for everything and would be happy if someone could prove me wrong and show me the right way. Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 0):

You're never actually turning your URL into a request and giving it to the `NSURLConnection`. Because of that, the connection will never complete, and its memory will stay allocated. You'll find a world of difference with the above code if you add this to your `connect:url:` method:

```
NSURLRequest* request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
```

...and pass that into your `NSURLConnection` so it actually does something:

```
self.test = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request  delegate:self];
```

...because then, as soon as the connection finishes doing its work—successfully or otherwise—its memory will be deallocated.

Comment: Sadly not changing a thing. Thats actually the way i implemented it in the app i was working on before i encountered this problem. Please try it for yourself

Comment: I tried it for myself before I posted. I ran your original code, and saw constantly-rising memory use peaking at around 8GB in the simulator. I ran it with my changes and it flattened out  at around 700MB. The only other difference with my code is that I'm grabbing simple default html page at `http://localhost/` rather than the `http://127.0.0.1/xmlfile.php` that I obviously don't have. Is it possible that your PHP file isn't returning properly, or something?

Comment: Incidentally, after it flattens out at around 700MB, the responses do start coming in, and gradually the memory usage falls as all 20,000 responses are processed. You do realise that you're virtually simultaneously queueing 20,000 asynchronous connections, and that your device might be somewhat overwhelmed by that, right? In the simulator it carries on like a trouper and several minutes later it manages to get through all 20,000. I'm guessing there's protection in the stack to stop you hitting a server too hard.